# Chartjs adding data values on the right legend

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

considering the following example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');
   var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
         labels: ["CL", "ML", "Spl.L", "PD", "Other Permissions"],
         datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: ['#F0CB8C', '#EE97A1', '#A9D5D4', '#E8A3D7', '#CFA3FD'],
            data: [7, 3, 3, 4, 8],
         }]
      },
      options: {
         legend: {
            position: 'right'
         }
      }
   });
})
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/xm80qzoo/)

is there a way to have the data on the right of the single label?
like here:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom labels as advised by [@LeeLenalee's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69370149/chartjs-show-value-in-legend-chart-js-v3-5)

and here is your workin code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');
   var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
         labels: ["CL", "ML", "Spl.L", "PD", "Other Permissions"],
         datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: ['#F0CB8C', '#EE97A1', '#A9D5D4', '#E8A3D7', '#CFA3FD'],
            data: [7, 3, 3, 4, 8],
         }]
      },
      options: {
         legend: {
        labels: {
          generateLabels: (chart) => {
            const datasets = chart.data.datasets;
            return datasets[0].data.map((data, i) => ({
              text: `${chart.data.labels[i]} ${data}`,
              fillStyle: datasets[0].backgroundColor[i],
            }))}
         }
       }
      }
   });
})
```

```css
.chart-container {
   width: 280px;
   height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-container">
   <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
</div>
```