# Create custom legend labels

Tags: chart.js

I need to add some custom labels to a chart.js legend and I tried to use the solution described here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69372812/28425.

Hover, with the following code

```js
var intervals = [ { min: 0.02, max: 1.44, mean: 0.73 },
                  { min: 0.06, max: 1.57, mean: 0.76 } ]

...

plugins: {
   legend: {
     labels: {
       generateLabels: (_chart) => {
         return intervals.map((obj, i) => {
           text: `UCL ${i} ${obj.max}`,
           fillStyle: '#34d399',
           index: i,
         })
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

I get `SyntaxError: unexpected token: ':'` on the `fillStyle` line.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is the syntax you are using to return the object by callback of `map` method. Being an object, you should put it in brackets.

```
plugins: {
  legend: {
     labels: {
       generateLabels: (_chart) => {
         return intervals.map((obj, i) => 
           ({
             text: `UCL ${i} ${obj.max}`,
             fillStyle: '#34d399',
             index: i,
           })
         );
       }
    }
  }
},
```